# How to make meteor subscription reactive?

Tags: meteor

I have a meteor 1.1.0.3 app, with the following code:

```
//Publishing:
Meteor.publish("movies", function () {
    var user  = Meteor.users.findOne({_id: this.userId});
    return movies.find({"imdbRating": {$gte: user.imdb_rating}});        
});

//Subscribing:
my_movies = Meteor.subscribe('movies', function() {
    return movies.find();
});
Router.route('/', function () {
    this.render('home', {
        data: {"movies": movies.find()}
    });
});

//Rendering:
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    ...
    <tbody>
        {{#each movies}}
            ...
        {{/each}}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In that way, my movies are not updated when there are new ones in the database. How can I make the table change the movies that are shown every time the publish query return different results?

Comment: You code seems like it should be reactive to changes in the db. The only weird thing I see is the callback in the `subscribe` and the assignment to `my_movies`. Why not just do `Meteor.subscribe('movies');`?

Comment: It doesn't change anything. My movies are still not reactive for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template Level Subscription I think should do it with an autorun block to watch for the database changes. https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/template-level-subscriptions/

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. And what if I still want to do it with Iron Router?Is there an easier way?

Comment: @alexarsh put your subscription into a `waitOn` hook